Why does my cat scream only at night in my mother's room?
Every night my mother has to make sure that the cats are out of the room before going to bed. If not, then our cat will start screaming at the top of his loungs as soon as she falls asleep. Or even when she is trying to take a nap. During the day he is completely fine with the door being open. He also only does it to her, I allow all of the cats in my bedroom,and have no problem with him screaming in there.

some sort of information about the cat had been nice,male/female,neutered or spayed,age,indoor/outdoor cat?
